# Go from one td input to another td input jquery

Tags: jquery

```
function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
        $('#headid' + item.SalaryHeadId).closest('tr').find('td:eq(3) input').val(data.Amount);
    });
});
```

here is the data [{"Amount":10622.50,"SalaryHeadId":2},{"Amount":700.00,"SalaryHeadId":3}];

What I am trying to do is: Find an input value which is in a td.Suppose, I get value 10 in the data.SalaryHeadId.

So, I need to find the td input which has value 10, then set some value in the forth column of the table which is also an input type. Here, Id of SalaryHeadId input is
 `headid+"Id Of Head"`
I don't have any clue how to do it.Thanks for having time on my issue

Update:Html only for two row.All the id's in the input type are added programmatically

```
<table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <tbody><tr>
        <th>
            Id
        </th>

        <th>
            HeadName
        </th>

        <th>
            Is Deduction
        </th>

        <th>
            Percentage
        </th>
        <th>
            Amount
        </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
         1
        </td>

        <td>
           <input type="text" value="1" name="item.Id" id="headid1" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val="true" class="headid">
            Basic
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" class="check-box">
            <label for="" class="lbl"> </label>
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="text" value="" name=" " id="Percentage1" class="percentage">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="" name=" " id="Amount1" class="amount">
        </td>
         </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
         12
        </td>

        <td>
           <input type="text" value="12" name="item.Id" id="headid12" class="headid">
            Govt. Part
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" class="check-box">
            <label for="" class="lbl"> </label>
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="text" value="" name=" " id="Percentage2" class="percentage">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="" name=" " id="Amount2" class="amount">
        </td>
         </tr>


</tbody></table>
```

Comment: can you share the html

Comment: is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you show how you set what data is?

Comment: @AndrewPolland data is in json format [{"Amount":10622.50,"SalaryHeadId":2},{"Amount":700.00,"SalaryHeadId":3}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See a working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hJ26p/2/

I think you just had a couple of errors. The syntax was a bit off on your function (it didn't have a name and hand a random bracket at the end). Not quite sure how you wanted it called, but I've changed it to being called when the document is ready.

Also you were using `data.Amount` instead of `item.Amount` to set the value.

This is the js code:

```
function setValues(data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
        $('#headid' + item.SalaryHeadId).closest('tr').find('td:eq(3) input').val(item.Amount);
    }); 
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    var values = [{"Amount":10622.50,"SalaryHeadId":2},{"Amount":700.00,"SalaryHeadId":3}];
    setValues(values);
});
```

Only other thing is to check your values match up with the ids. I know you only posted a sample of data, but the data values and the html didn't match at all. Which just meant I got stuck for a moment. Probably not an issue for you (I just edited the ids in the html slightly to get it working).

Comment: great, there was no error but I use data instead of item thanks.I happens when try to something quickly.Thanks so much

Comment: @janina No problem. Glad I could help. So often it's just something small that you just can't see.